# ImportError: No module named object_detection.builders in colab google

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, google-colaboratory

I have this error when i run

```
%cd

!git clone --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

!apt-get install -qq protobuf-compiler python-tk

!pip install -q Cython contextlib2 pillow lxml matplotlib PyDrive

!pip install -q pycocotools

%cd ~/models/research
!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ':/content/models/research/:/content/models/research/slim/'

!python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

I got this

```
/root/models/research
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 23, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
ImportError: No module named object_detection.builders
```

Someone can help me please, i've working a lot of time in this

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install tensorflow-object-detection-api
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is unable to find the module "object_detection". 
Solution:

- Get the module
- Fix(include) the path to the module.

See if this helps:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1832